# How can I get an line under the original data

Tags: matlab

I have data about only black line and I want to get the yellow area. 
So how can I get the red line on MATLAB?
Please help me.

[image: Sample]

Comment: I guess it would be easier to help you if you posted a [mcve] including sample data and your current code.

Comment: It's easy, you just have to open Matlab and code an algorithm that calculates the red line given the the black one... Oh wait, you wanted us to do it for you??

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of information. I have only data points about black line and I just asked which function I can use for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
%create a sample periodic curve
t=0:.1:31.4;
upper = (100-t.^2).*cos(t+pi);

%take first derivative of the curve
diff1 = diff(upper);

%find the lowest points of the original curve
lower_x = find([diff1>0 0] & [0 diff1<0]); %rising zero crossings
lower_y = upper(lower_x);

%interpolate between points of the lower curve
lower = spline(lower_x,lower_y,0:size(t,2)-1);

%display
figure; hold on;
plot(t,upper,'b');
plot(t,lower,'r');
```